# AMD Athlon 7550 with Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, 64-bit, 32-bit, amd-athlon

I am currently working on a computer for a friend with an AMD Athlon 7550 Dual-Core Processor running windows vista 32 bit. I want to know if it is possible to upgrade this to windows 7 64 bit and if the preformance would be objectively better/worse. This processor advertized to have AMD64 technology (aka 64 bit compatibility) but it is only dual core/2 threads. Does anybody have any experience with this? or is it better to stay on 32 bit operating systems?
thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot 'upgrade' **any** 32-bit Windows to 64-bit. You have to wipe & start afresh. As neither Vista nor Win 7 are currently supported, unless you are considering going to Win 10 you're probably best off staying where you are [& staying off the internet with it].

Comment: It would be best for your friend to buy a new computer. Such an old computer might be too fragile to survive such onerous operations.

Comment: my apologies for not being very clear, yes i know that i cant just "upgrade" and have to do a complete wipe. I understand that buying a new computer is the better option for up-to-date machine, however my friend is mostly looking to relive some older games and software that is on this computer. I mostly wanted to know if there would be severe changes in preformance if i would change the os to something that is from around the same time (also windows vista is not really as stable as windows 7 in my experience and lisence keys are unfortunatelly no longer available for vista).

Comment: And yes connecting to the internet was not a requirement, the computer is purely for nostalgic purposes and wont be used for daily browsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.  You can *reinstall* Windows 7 64 bit to that computer.  I doubt you would see a performance difference.  Always double check that there are 64 bit drivers available, first.

Comment: Thank you Keltari, that was what i was mostly curious about, if 64bit was even posibble.